# Vue JS: check if user logged in not working in my code

Tags: vue.js, session

in my Vue Js project i wanted to check if user logged in so he can access website and if not it should take him to `/login` page.. since i'm new to Vue Js i tried the below code but it didn't work in app.js, can someone please help me in this ?

```js
  mounted: function(){
       if(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.user)){
          console.log(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.user))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value from sessionStorage. Something like this would work

```
sessionStorage.getItem('name of the key')
```

Comment: what do you mean by the name of the key ididn't really get it?

Comment: By name of the key I meant by what name it is getting stored in the session storage. Data is always stored in key/value pair in web storage.